# Latex macros in \ClassWarning or \ClassError

Tags: spacing, expansion, documentclass-writing

I want to tell a user to add a certain command to their preamble in a `\ClassError`. I try to do this with

```
\ClassError{myclass}{Please add \noexpand\makro=1}
```

The problem is that the error message that is printed reads

```
Class   myclass Error: Please add \makro =1
```

LaTeX somehow adds a space before the after `\makro`.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: `\string` will work

Comment: Great, thanks! `\string` instead of `\noexpand` does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
Please add \string\makro=1
```